# Customizing Associated Records displayed in the Form Assistant (MS CRM 4.0)

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-4

I've recently customized the lookup functionality of MS CRM 4.0 to filter a contact list to only those contacts owned by a client using techniques similar to the one presented here:

http://advantageworks.blogspot.com/2008/02/pseudo-filtered-lookup-dialog-in.html

My question is, can I apply the same type of logic to the Form Assistant pane within the window?  I've currently disabled the form assistant to prevent confusion, but I'd very much like to filter those contacts as well.  I like the inline AJAX presentation of that data more than the lookup pop-up window, but I can't find any information on how that thing is working.

Anyone out there done this before?

Thanks in advance!
Bob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell from the research I've done - customization of the Form Assistant pane in MS CRM 4.0 in this manner simply is not possible.  In those cases where we required this customization we opted to hide the Form Assistant to prevent end-user confusion.

Boo MS.

Boo.